# Daphne not logging errors

Tags: daphne

I have the following systemd config

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/srv/www/project_a/project_a/
Environment=JSON_SETTINGS=/srv/www/project_a/project_a.json
ExecStart=/srv/www/project_a/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 project_a.asgi:channel_layer
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGTERM
NotifyAccess=all
StandardOut=file:/tmp/daphne-access.log
StandardError=file:/tmp/daphne-error.log
```

But the daphne-access.log and daphone-error.log files are both empty, I thought daphne's default logging out be outputting to stdout?

Tried: `--access-log=/tmp/daphne-access.log` which worked for access logs, but don't know where to get django errors when they happen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add the following to your `LOGGING['loggers']` settings:

```
'daphne': {
    'handlers': [
        'console',
    ],
    'level': 'DEBUG'
},
```

Comment: Just keep in mind, that will log EVERYTHING, not suitabel for production. For Prod, set the level to warning or error.

Comment: You may set `'console'` handler's formatter to `"django.server"` as well, to get the format that default `runserver` command provides in stdout.

Answer (score 1):

For django errors you need to define django logs. please refer the documentation for more information.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/